# how to find k in k-means when there is a mix of categorical and numerical data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using a variation of k-means called k-prototype clustering as implemented in the kmodes package, which works when there is a mixture of categorical and numerical data.

https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes

How do I find the appropriate number of clusters for this?

Answer (score 2):

Appropriate number of clusters in kmodes can be found in the same manner as in KMeans. The techniques of [Silhouette Coefficient](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#silhouette-coefficient) can be used for kmodes. But the `metric` should not be used as `euclidean` instead `cosine` metric could be used.